# Edit MySQL my.cfn With phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to edit my.cfn file.
Can I do it with phpMyAdmin (Version 4.4.15) 
and where can I find this file?

Comment: I think some members of this forum have hobby to add dislike to the question, Instead answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. phpMyAdmin can only manage content of databases and variables of running instances, it cannot modify configuration of mysql server itself.